# How do you create a watermark for photos?

Tags: post-processing, watermark

How do I create a watermark?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of ways to create a watermark, with varying degress of ease.

- An application that allows you to "apply" a watermark during image export. This is pretty straightforward. Adobe Lightroom has this option.
- An image hosting company that lets you apply watermarks to all uploaded images. This is also straightforward, though can be a paid-for feature. Smugmug has watermark capabilities for "Pro" accounts.
- Image editing applications have recordable sequences that can be played back on to an image. You would record the sequence of steps of manually applying a water mark. Then replay this sequence on an image as needed, to produce a watermark.
- Manually create a watermark.

For the last two options, the steps to create a water mark are usually:

1. Create a new layer
2. Add text or an image in the desired location on the new layer
3. Flatten the image

Obviously this requires an image editor that supports layers (almost all do these days).

Answer (score 10):

There are two types of watermark, visible and invisible. Visible watermarks are usually added to "brand" an image, add your name and copyright information, in order to deter image theft (though it wont prevent it). They can be easily added by creating a new text layer in Photoshop/Gimp.

Invisible watermarks are used to help track images and are a more effective way to prevent copyright theft as they are resistant to image transformations (rotation, cropping etc). They can be added by plugins such as Digimark.

Comment: What do you mean by "Gimp?"

Comment: It's a free image editing program that's available for many different operating systems. See http://www.gimp.org