# How Do I Add Copyright Information to My Nikon D5200?

Tags: camera-settings, copyright, nikon-d5200

I recently came across [this](http://www.diyphotography.net/photographer-has-15k-in-gear-stolen-uses-exif-data-to-nail-the-thief/) article which documents how a photographer tracked down his $15k worth of stolen gear by identifying images set with his copyright in the metadata.

I would like to do the same with my Nikon D5200, but there is no *Copyright Information* in my *Setup* menu as I've read to do on Nikon Cameras.

Some have recommended adding "Copyright John Smith" to the *Image Comment* section in the Setup Menu, but does that actually accomplish the same thing in the EXIF data?

**EDIT:**

I enabled Image Comment and see that it does store the information in the EXIF data:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Every camera have different setting for such settings.

For example, on Canon DSLR:

[image: Canon Copyright Info]

On Nikon DSLR:

[image: Nikon Copyright Info]

On some camera it's called image comment:

[image: Nikon D5200 EXIF]

Every camera have different layout so you might want to refer to the manual.
Are you using point-to-shoot? Chances are the device doesn't have the option.

Comment: The Nikon D5200 does not have a Copyright Information subsection in the  Setup menu. Thanks though.

Comment: I found your model, check the section called `image comment`.
I mis-seen the title...

Comment: That was part of the question. I'm not sure if "Image Comment" acts in the same way as "Copyright Information."

Comment: It does, both of the section involves injecting EXIF data into the image. Albeit in a different section, but can still be extracted.

Comment: If it's just an image comment, you could add `Copyright: ` at the start of your name, so anyone viewing the metadata will be able to clearly see what the name means

Comment: After setting the image comments the photo doesn’t show the image comment

Comment: @Akash This puts the copyright info into the EXIF data.  It is not visible in the photo.  If you want something visible, you want to do a watermark. See https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/how-do-you-create-a-watermark-for-photos

Comment: @Akash That's a good thing right? If it was shown in every picture a thief would notice and delete your name. If it is hidden, you have evidence if someone is trying to sell your stolen camera to you.